# ipython emacs IndentationError

Tags: emacs, ipython

Really annoying problem in ipython prompt in emacs:

```
In [128]: if 1==1:
   .....:     print "yes"
   .....: else:    
   .....:     print "no"
   .....:     
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

It looks perfectly aligned to me, not sure what trigger the error. No such problem when I do this in terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem. And it happens in any shell in emacs (eg. eshell) after calling ipython, not only in the ipython shell (M-x ipython) provided by python-mode.el or ipython.el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try toggling autoindent with

`%autoindent`

since I think that has caused the problem for me before.

You can change this permanently using [ipython's customization](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html).  After the proper imports (see the link) the following should work in ipy_user_conf.py:

```
# Emacs sets the term to dumb so we can distinguish that way
if os.environ['TERM'] == 'dumb':
    ip.options.autoindent = 0
```

Comment: That solves the problem! Is there any way to save this instruction to avoid having to type it each time ipython mode is started again?

Comment: I added a note about making it permanent.  There might be an emacs only way to call `%autoindent` when ipython starts, but that seems less reliable since `%autoindent` always toggles AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is strange. On my end, using the standard `python` interpreter within an emacs shell works fine when evaluating your code, but using `ipython` fails. If you're using the `python-mode.el` package, you probably need to install `ipython.el` to get proper `ipython` support. OTOH, if you're using the `python.el` that normally ships with emacs, you may have to switch to the standard `python` interpreter (I believe `ipython.el` is only intended for use with the third-party `python-mode.el` package, not the `python.el` that emacs uses by default).